# Creating Firewall rule for a process running in a Non-admin user account

Tags: c++, windows, security, firewall, non-admin

I have a basic requirement - to run my application smoothly on Windows by creating firewall rules when prompted, that has windows firewall turned-ON.

When I log in to my system as an user with Admin privileges when I run my application the first time, the firewall comes up with a prompt, I inform it to allow my app and create a rule, nice.

However when I turn-on my PC, log in as a non-Admin user, and I run my application, the firewall shows up with a prompt as expected; however when I click on the same options as I did from the Admin user, the firewall prompt keeps popping up continuously even though I clicked on Allow /ok every time the prompt appears. The prompt only goes away when I click on "Cancel / Block" the application from running, which is obviously not what I want to do.

So here comes the million $ question, What and How should I change my application code to run smoothly by creating the firewall rule successfully the first time I click on the firewall prompt to allow my application; exactly the same way it is working when I run my application as an user with Admin privileges.

I have done my bit of searching online and have come to understand that Non-admin users cannot modify firewall rules (cannot even create them???). BTW I have tested this scenario on Windows XP, Vista 7 both x86 and x64 with same results.

If someone has encountered and / or solved similar issues please share your knowledge. If I am missing something, please make me understand what I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying is possible in a `non-admin` account. What you may try is to gain `admin` privilege by using the windows `runas` feature by creating a new process, so that the user is prompted for the `username` and `password` of the Admin Account, which would give your program the required access to create firewall rules for your program.

You may also take a look into [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LogOnUSer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . Basically in order to succeed in what you are trying to do, you need a token that represents the Administrator account or an account which has admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks. I actually am calling CreateProcessAsUser but still have this issue. I will play around with the flags/parameters and see how it behaves. I do not think I can use LogOnUser in my scenario.